# OSX PKG installer completes but dotnet not installed

Tags: coreclr

I am attempting to install .Net Core on my OSX laptop and following the instructions at https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/.  I've downloaded the PKG and installed it successfully (along with its dependency OpenSSL).  However, when I attempt to run `dotnet` from the command line I get a `command not found` error.

What should I do to fix this and get the `dotnet` CLI to be installed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the installer had some symbolic links missing on post-installation, there is already a fix for this but not sure if it is in the latest pkg as the time of writing.

You could create the symbolic links yourself:

`$ ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/bin/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
$ ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/bin/csc /usr/local/bin/`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

to today work this for me

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a bit weird but I had the same problem and the only thing I did was reopening the terminal and writing `dotnet new mvc` then it worked like a charm!

Thanks to the answer on Github issue given by **flyingsky** in the following link: [Command not found dotnet Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2544)